# Testing for 0 after gets

Tags: assembly, control-flow, instructions

Hey I have a snippet of assembly code that does not make sense to me

```
.text:004016C5 prompt_uid:             ; "[ User %d    ]\t"
.text:004016C5 mov     [esp+0Ch+var_C], offset aUserD
.text:004016CC mov     ecx, [ebp+arg_0]
.text:004016CF mov     [esp+0Ch+var_8], ecx
.text:004016D3 call    printf
.text:004016D8 mov     [esp+0Ch+var_C], esi
.text:004016DB call    gets
.text:004016E0 test    eax, eax        ; test eax=0
.text:004016E2 jz      short prompt_uid
```

At first I was confused by the `test eax,eax` and `jz` following a `gets`.

"Why would any input be 0?". Then I thought 
"Ok. strings are terminated by a nullbyte so an empty string should result in the test setting ZF"

But when I tested it in practice the jz was never taken. Even when I just hit enter at the prompt.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gets() reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/gets.html) gives the answer to when it will return NULL;

> RETURN VALUE
>
> Upon successful completion, gets() shall return s. **If the stream is at
>   end-of-file**, the end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set and
>   gets() shall return a null pointer. **If a read error occurs**, the error
>   indicator for the stream shall be set, gets() shall return a null
>   pointer, [CX]   and set errno to indicate the error.

In other words, `gets()` may return NULL on end of file or a read error, not in normal "press return" operation.

Comment: Aah! I was making two mistakes here a) I forgot the result was actually written to the buffer supplied as an argument b) I did'nt think about EOF.